# Error while storing date in MongoDB from R

Tags: r, mongodb

I am using RMongo library for storing data in mongo from R.
This is the script I am trying to run:

```
time <- "2016-12-31T23:55:43.002513Z";
mongo <- mongoDbConnect(dbName, hostName , port);
output <- dbInsertDocument(mongo, collectionName , paste0('{"Param1":', 1, ',"Param2":', 2, ',"TimeStamp":',time, '}', sep = "", collapse = ""));
```

Error I am getting is:

```
Error in .jcall(rmongo.object@javaMongo, "S", "dbInsertDocument",   collection,  : 
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{"Param1":1,"Param2":2,"TimeStamp":2016-12-31T23:55:43.002513Z}
                                       ^
```

What format should I be passing the timestamp here?

Comment: If anyone is aware of other ways to store Dates into MongoDB (in UTC format) from R, please do share.

Comment: If you're inserting a `data.frame`, then `library(mongolite)` will insert it correctly. However, I've not found a reliable way of doing it if your data is in a list/JSON/other.. [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41504780/5977215)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi thanks [SymbolixAU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5977215/symbolixau). This worked for me.

```
 library(mongolite)

 m <- mongo(collection = collectionName , db = dbName, url = hostName);

 df <- data.frame(Param1 = 1, Param2 = 2, TimeStamp=as.POSIXct(time,tz="UTC"));

 m$insert(df);
```

Just posting this for others' reference.